# Subgroup decomposition

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $K_1,K_2$ be strict normal subgroups of group $G$, $G =K_1K_2$ and $H \leq G$. Is it true that $H = (H \cap K_1)(H \cap K_2)$?
Can we relax the normal condition by considering conditions on $H$ or $G$?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the same person asked this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't true. Consider $G = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$. Then $G = K_1 K_2$, where
$$
K_1 = \mathbb Z \times \{0\}$$ and $$K_2 = \{0\} \times \mathbb Z.
$$
Then consider the subgroup
$$
H := \{(n, n)|n \in \mathbb Z\}.
$$
Its intersection with both $K_1$ and $K_2$ is zero, yet it is nontrivial.

Comment: This is the problem 6.21 from the book “A course on finite groups” by Rose!

Comment: I didn't know that book yet. But you can make the groups finite, if you want to, by replacing $\mathbb Z$ by $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ for some $m \ge 2$.

Comment: Is this true for finite groups?

Comment: No it's not! What I meant was: The counter-example above may be modified to work for finite groups.

Comment: Is there any result for subgroup decomposition from group decomposition?

Comment: Perhaps you could get somewhere by having one factor be contained within the subgroup, but I'm not sure.